# Tooltip on split button of WPF Ribbon Controls Library

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tooltip, ribboncontrolslibrary, split-button

I am using Microsoft's [Ribbon Control Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (RibbonControlsLibrary.dll) for my WPF application using Dotnet framework 4.0.
It works good for me.

I have a issue regarding using split button.
Split button of this library i.e. `RibbonSplitButton` does not show tool tip.
However children of this split button show their tool tips properly.

Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **`ToolTipTitle`** property instead of the `ToolTip`